# How to set req.params parameters in Node's supertest?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, supertest

My OAuth middleware expects to get parameters in req.params.

```
request(app)
.post('/api/token')
.set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
.send({grant_type:'password'})
.expect(200)
```

`.send({grant_type:'password'})` doesn't help. I don't know what it is used for.

Comment: you might have to pass in the actual `app` object you're testing against so the request object knows about your the dynamic param values

Answer (score 2):

You can use a supertest like this for the same requirement

```
const app = require('../server'),
chai = require('chai'),
should = require('should'),
request = require('supertest');

describe("/get /:userId", () => {
it("should fetch user by id successfully", (done) => {
    request(app)
        .get("/users/" + userId)
        // .query({ userId: userId })
        .set('Accept', 'application/json')
        .set({ 'x-access-token': token })
        .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
        .end((err, res) => {
            res.status.should.equal(200);
            // console.log("res.body.data.users = ",res.body)
            // res.body.should.a("object");
            res.body.data.should.have.property("users");
            done();
        });
});
```

});

Answer (score 1):

express puts stuff `req.params` automatically. if you define a route `something/:name` then it should be on `req.params.name`. From the [documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.params):

> This property is an object containing properties mapped to the named
>   route “parameters”. For example, if you have the route /user/:name,
>   then the “name” property is available as req.params.name. This object
>   defaults to {}.

So if you do the supertest example

```
request(app)
.post('/api/token')
.set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
.send({grant_type:'password'})
.expect(200)
```

the `.send({grant_type:'password'})` part populates the `req.body` in express not the `req.params`.